# Getting devices to see each other in a nested network

Tags: networking, router

I have a nested network structure at home: one router (router 1) connected to the internet (and providing main wifi at home) and another router (router 2) in my study to provide wired access to a couple of devices. I specifically didn't set up router 2 as a wireless access point only as I also run a VPN server on it.

Router 2 WAN is connected to router 1 and has a WAN IP of 192.168.0.x and all other devices under router 2 have 192.168.1.x IP addresses.
What I want to do is to be able to configure the network so that I can print on a printer connected to router 2 (under 192.168.1.x) from a laptop connected to router 1 (under 192.168.0.x). Currently I can get all devices connected to router 2 see all devices under 1 (as 2 is WAN'ed to 1) but not the other way around.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will be simpler (I think) to have everything on one subnet.

Hook up Router 2 to your network using a LAN port (not the WAN port).

Give Router 2 a static IP address on the main network.

Turn DHCP OFF on Router 2.

Now all devices and printers on the network can be seen by other devices.

After you make changes, restart both routers

I do this myself and it works very well.

Now it may need another small router, you can add that for your VPN and the proceed to have all other devices (most importantly the printer) on one subnet. That also can work.

Comment: Many thanks John. Isn't this the same as running router 2 as a wireless access point though? The problem with that is that I can't keep running the VPN server that is on router 2 if I go down that route.

Comment: It should not hurt your VPN setup and you can use wireless on Router 2 assuming it has wireless.  The subnetting should not affect this. To put it another way, if you had one router you could do all that you are trying to do.

Comment: You can also add a small router for VPN to accommodate VPN and all other needs. I amended my answer to address this situation.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct, if I had one router that would simply solve this problem but I can't do away with router 1 as it serves part of a mesh and it doesn't support VPN. Router 2 is needed for the VPN and the wired connection setup needed for home office. I can try and solve the problem by getting a small network switch and wire connect everything in the home office subnet including router 2 to move everything into one subnet. Still, that's unfortunately not flexible enough to allow access if the printer is wirelessly connected to router 2.

Comment: I think a small router would not be much more expensive than a switch, and that will solve your problem with all the flexibility you need.